# MediaPlayer вылетает на этапе setDataSource

Tags: android, mediaplayer

В программе одна активность вызывает другую с передачей uri аудиофайла. Во второй активности MediaPlayer проигрывает файл по нажатию кнопки. Аудиофайл хранится в памяти эмулятора. При первом запуске эмулятора все работает как надо. Если закрыть эмулятор и открыть повторно, происходит крах программы во второй активности на этапе setDataSource при создании MediaPlayer'а. Проверял при отладке что uri при первом и втором запуске идентичны. Если сделать Wipe Data, то первый запуск опять проходит успешно. Похоже что причина в параметре applicationContext, который указывается в setDataSource. Подскажите в чем может быть проблема?

Привожу код второй активности.

```
class AudioPlay : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var mPlayer: MediaPlayer

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_audioplay)

        val myUri = intent.data!!

        mPlayer = MediaPlayer().apply {
            setAudioAttributes(
                    AudioAttributes.Builder()
                            .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC)
                            .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_MEDIA)
                            .build()
            )
            setDataSource(applicationContext, myUri)
            prepare()
        }
    }

    fun audioClick(view: View) {
        when (view.id) {
            R.id.btAUPlay -> {
                mPlayer.start()
            }
            R.id.btAUStop -> {
                mPlayer.pause()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Не забывайте прикреплять stacktrace (лог ошибок).

Answer (score 0):

Надеюсь решение моей проблемы поможет какому-нибудь начинающему вроде меня.
Причина проблемы заключалась в том, что Андроид дает возможность обращаться к файлу через Uri в случае, если пользователь сам выбрал этот файл. После перезагрузки устройства или эмулятора Uri теряет свои права. Чтобы Uri продолжал действовать после перезагрузки устройства, нужно запросить для конкретного Uri *the persistable URI permission*. Здесь [ссылка](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files#persist-permissions) на официальную документацию. Я добавил этот фрагмент кода в функцию onActivityResult, где получаю Uri аудиофайла от интента. После этого все заработало как надо.

```
    val contentResolver = applicationContext.contentResolver
    val takeFlags: Int = Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
    contentResolver.takePersistableUriPermission(myUri, takeFlags)
```